# .htacess for removing public/index.php works good in root and not in sub directories

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is my `.htaccess` which i have default in laravel it helps me to prevent typing `public/index.php`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

So, if i need to access

```
localhost/public/index.php/home
localhost/public/index.php/login
```

It is enough to me to type

```
localhost/home
localhost/login
```

I want to make exception to for few directories such as 'testproject' and 'betaproject' i.e., where i will have a regular php or html directory or i will have another fresh project and it will have same .htaccess also.

**How can i modify my .htaccess file to make it possible.**

So that if i want to access

`localhost/testproject/public/index.php/home` should be accessible by `localhost/testproject/home`

Answer (score 0):

In your root .htaccess have this rule to skip 2 directories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(testproject|betaproject)/(\w+)/?$ $1/public/index.php/$2 [L,NC]
```

Make sure this rule is very first just below `RewriteEngine On` line.